# REST request to query Google datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

Is there a way to make a POST request to query google datastore and get back results? I know there's a way to do this with BigQuery, but I'm unable to find a way to query DS.

Google API docs mention the runQuery request but that doesn't come back with the results.
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/runQuery#QueryResultBatch

To be more specific, I get the response below when I call runQuery:

**Request body to runQuery**

```
{
  "gqlQuery": {
    "allowLiterals": true,
    "queryString": "SELECT * from Products where name > 'App' "
  }
}
```

**Response body**

```
"batch": {
    "moreResults": "NO_MORE_RESULTS", 
    "endCursor": "CgA=", 
    "entityResultType": "FULL"
  }
```

My expectation was that the batch object should have the results.

Would appreciate any help!
Thanks,
Sammy

Comment: Please, make sure you provided full response body. It seems that you copy only part of it.

Comment: Can you show the value of an entity which you think should have been included in the result? Is the `name` property indexed?

Comment: Does the same query in the Developer console (https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/query/gql) shows results?